# Trying To Send Email via .NET function

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm trying to send an email using the code below, and I get this error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
```

I've already allowed unsecure applications to send me emails and turned off my 2-Step Verification on my `gmail`, and of course I replaced    `Net.NetworkCredential("myvalidemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")` with my real email and password, but I still get that error.
I am running the program through `VB` debug, but that shouldn't matter.

```
Private Sub SendBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SendBtn.Click
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
    Net.NetworkCredential("myvalidemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("myvalidemail@gmail.com")
        mail.To.Add("myvalidemail@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("mail send")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I really wish this had a tidy dupe....

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that SMTP server requires a secure connection. Try enabling the SSL

```
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

"client was not authenticated"
Just a thought: do you use Google Two Factor Authorization?